# Knockout and MVC 2.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, knockout.js

Does anyone know of an example application using knockout js and MVC 2?  I'm trying to learn knockout and am having trouble grasping how to persist model data via an ajax call to an action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a great post [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) by the author of Knockout on how to use it with MVC. In MVC 2 you can use the built in model binder instead of a `[FromJson]` attribute like the article suggests.

Congrats on finding Knockout. My team has absolutely loved working with it. One of our guys replaced a dynamic silverlight grid control that took weeks of development with a knockout form (w/ even more functionality!) in less than a day. It's a great framework for dealing with lists on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Kudos on replacing the grid. Have you had any issues with the default model binder and posting grid data back to an action?

Comment: @jsteve Yeah there are a few tricks. I'll try to brainstorm a list of them and post it tomorrow from work.

Comment: @Ryan, did you get a chance to compile the list of tricks? it would be helpful to post them here

Comment: I second Vin's request.  Knockout tips please!

Comment: @Vin @Dirk The biggest issue we had was not actually KO, but javascript itself. We have a model that returns a nullable decimal property. In order to not show 'null' when a property is null we use `ThisIsNull || ''` to get an empty string instead of 'null'. However, if you have a `0` value to show, it also gets rendered as an empty string since `0` is "falsy" in javascript. We ended up returning all ints and decimals as strings in our view model to get around this.

Comment: Ran into another issue today. Posting back an unedited `int?` was returning an int in json but not binding correctly on the server. I had to use `.toString()` in the client to get it to work correctly. Seems the model binder has issues with nullable number types if the posted value isn't a string. :( This is in MVC2 btw.

Comment: More notes: Knockout now has a mapping plug-in that resolves the issues that I've mentioned above. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I have ported the knockout samples to .NET MVC3 (Razor)-- with restful data access. The url is
http://harshbhasin.com/opensource/ko